# Primefaces commandLink immediate=true, does not work as expected

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have two Primefaces (drop-down & link) component as below. 
In one scenario I hide the mandatory drop-down field and has only the link.
When I click the link, I expect it to open the link immediately.
But it expects to select a value from the drop-down, even though it is hidden.

Component-1

```
            <h:panelGroup id="countriesMultiSelect">
                <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="countries" label="Countries"
                    value="#{reportsBean.selectedCountriesISOCode}" filter="true"
                    filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:200px"
                    rendered="#{reportsBean.renderCountriesMultiSelect}"
                    required="true"
                    style="#{ not component.valid ? 'background-color:#FFCCCC' : ''}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{cirAppBean.euCountries}" var="country"
                        itemValue="#{country.isoCountryCode}"
                        itemLabel="#{country.countryName}" />
                </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
            </h:panelGroup>
```

Component-2

```
                <p:commandLink action="#{reportsBean.viewCreditInstitutionAction}"
                    value="#{institutionHierarchy.institutionName}" immediate="true"
                    rendered="#{institutionHierarchy.institutionId ne null}">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{reportsBean.institutionId}"
                        value="#{institutionHierarchy.institutionId}" />
                </p:commandLink>
```

Any one know why ?

Comment: Why do you hide the mandatory fields?

Comment: The problem is if you set the filed as required the form won't submit until and unless you provide the value.

Comment: @Makky thanks. This mandatory field is only needed for some scenarios.  This rule is driven from another drop-down (A) value. For some of the value for drop-down (A), I need to hide this drop-down (component-1). And when this drop-down (component-1) is hidden I do not want it to give mandatory field required error message.

Comment: @Makky thanks. I thought if its not rendered, its out of the picture and its required property would never be considered.

Comment: You should bypass validation for the required selectCheckboxMenu  processing only the commandLink. Use **process="@this"** in your commandLink.

Comment: @Jay if it is not rendered then you don't need to pass value . Is that not working ?

Comment: @Makky / user2251135 thanks for the inputs. process="@this" solved the issue. In fact there was another bug which did not load the needed data when I click the hyperlink and remains in the same page. So when I click the link from 2nd time onward I started getting this required field error.  After I fix the data load issue it works fine now even without the process="@this". But I learned this new useful attribute as well. Thanks Guys.